# Using effects package inside a function

Tags: r

I have a large frame with lots of variables which I'm going to analyze in the same way. Specifically, I want to plot effect confidence intervals in mixed effect model. I want to write function which make a custom plot for one dependent variable. Direct application of effect() function goes well. But the same code inside function cause error.

I tried two variants of function. Both cause errors.

Here is my reproducible example:

```r
library(nlme)
library(effects)

df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(90), x = gl(3, 30), b = factor(rep(1:30, 3)))

fit <- lme(fixed = y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | b, data = df, method = "REML")
ef <- effect("x", fit)
bp <- barplot(as.vector(ef$fit), col = c("tomato", "skyblue", "limegreen"), 
        ylim = c(min(ef$lower), max(ef$upper) + (max(ef$upper) - min(ef$lower)) * 0.2 ))
arrows(x0 = bp, y0 = ef$lower, y1 = ef$upper, code = 3, angle = 90)

test1 <- function(y, x, b)
{
  fit <- lme(fixed = y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | b, method = "REML")
  ef <- effect("x", fit)
  bp <- barplot(as.vector(ef$fit), col = c("tomato", "skyblue", "limegreen"), 
                ylim = c(min(ef$lower), max(ef$upper) + (max(ef$upper) - min(ef$lower)) * 0.2 ))
  arrows(x0 = bp, y0 = ef$lower, y1 = ef$upper, code = 3, angle = 90)
}

test1(df$y, df$x, df$b)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found 

test2 <- function(y, x, b)
{
  frame <- data.frame(y, x, b)

  fit <- lme(fixed = y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | b, frame, method = "REML")
  ef <- effect("x", fit)
  bp <- barplot(as.vector(ef$fit), col = c("tomato", "skyblue", "limegreen"), 
                ylim = c(min(ef$lower), max(ef$upper) + (max(ef$upper) - min(ef$lower)) * 0.2 ))
  arrows(x0 = bp, y0 = ef$lower, y1 = ef$upper, code = 3, angle = 90)
}

test2(df$y, df$x, df$b)
# Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
#  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: You need to pass data to `lme`. This is why `test1` doesn't work. When you write `y~x` you just define a formula, you don't actually use the `y` and `x` passed as argument.  Not sure why `test2` doesn't work: it looks like `frame` was understood as `graphics::frame` instead of the data.frame. Maybe you didn't run the function as shown here. In any case, the solution is to pass df to your function rather than y, x, b.

Comment: `lme()` works fine even in my `test1()` case. The problem arises when `effect()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
function(df) {
  fit <- lme(fixed = y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | b, data = df, method = "REML")
  ef <- effect("x", fit)
  bp <- barplot(as.vector(ef$fit), col = c("tomato", "skyblue", "limegreen"),
                ylim = c(min(ef$lower), 
                         max(ef$upper) + (max(ef$upper) - min(ef$lower)) * 0.2 ))
  arrows(x0 = bp, y0 = ef$lower, y1 = ef$upper, code = 3, angle = 90)
}
```

You need to pass `data` to `lme`, the formula doesn't actually pass any data.

That said, your `test2` should work. I can replicate your error but it is really very weird. Somehow the code works in the global env but not in the closure. Very surprising.

Comment: Your code works. But my problem is that I have dozens of `y` in my real frame which I need to analyze with same `x` and `b`. And idea was to write a function which produce customized plot with stat results and to call it for different `y`-s. I need to pass different variable into my function (either as data or as variable name)..